# Inno Setup: Finding registry entry

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

On a command line, the following returns the correct result:

```
REG Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office" /s /f "MyEntry"
```

How to do it with Inno Setup?

That means:
How do I start with a certain key and then how can I look into all subfolders to find a certain value?
The Code should return the full path.

rgds

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather vague. The given `reg query` command will look for both key names, value names and values. It seems unlikely, such query is useful for a real program.

But anyway, to recursively iterate a registry key, use the code below. Add your own tests to find, what you are really after:

```pascal
procedure RegSearch(RootKey: Integer; KeyName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Names: TArrayOfString;
  Name: string;
begin
  if RegGetSubkeyNames(RootKey, KeyName, Names) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names) - 1 do
    begin
      Name := KeyName + '\' + Names[I];

      Log(Format('Found key %s', [Name]));

      RegSearch(RootKey, Name);
    end;
  end;

  if RegGetValueNames(RootKey, KeyName, Names) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names) - 1 do
    begin
      Name := KeyName + '\' + Names[I];

      Log(Format('Found value %s', [Name]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

To start the search, call the function like:

```pascal
RegSearch(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Office');
```